# Share a folder programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, file-sharing

I have an OS X application that lets the user select any folder. I need to somehow share that selected folder on the network. I have been doing research for a while on how to share a folder using Objective-C; nothing helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the built-in (AFP/SMB) File Sharing service, you can use the [Open Directory framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/Introduction/Introduction.html) to edit records of type `kODRecordTypeSharePoints`.  Your best bet is to examine what System Preferences does when you add a share point and just copy that format.  You can use `dscl` to examine it, for example:

```
% dscl . -list /SharePoints
Previous iTunes Libraries
% dscl . -read '/SharePoints/Previous iTunes Libraries'
dsAttrTypeNative:afp_guestaccess: 1
dsAttrTypeNative:afp_name:
 Previous iTunes Libraries
dsAttrTypeNative:afp_shared: 1
dsAttrTypeNative:directory_path:
 /Users/nicholas/Music/iTunes/Previous iTunes Libraries
dsAttrTypeNative:ftp_name:
 Previous iTunes Libraries
dsAttrTypeNative:sharepoint_group_id: 33FBCB64-3B80-4E8E-A262-CC2D885A0B0E
dsAttrTypeNative:smb_createmask: 644
dsAttrTypeNative:smb_directorymask: 755
dsAttrTypeNative:smb_guestaccess: 1
dsAttrTypeNative:smb_name:
 Previous iTunes Libraries
dsAttrTypeNative:smb_shared: 1
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName:
 Previous iTunes Libraries
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:SharePoints
```

`dscl` also has an interactive mode which is more useful for exploring.

Comment: Read the documentation; I'm not going to write your code for you.

Comment: Thannks. This works in Terminal. But how to use it in Application, to share folder using Objective C?